# Why need ReaderLock?

Tags: java, locking

Since the readers don't change anything, why we need ReaderLock?

Comment: ReaderLock as in `ReentrantReadWriteLock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one you don't want a writer writing while a reader is reading, because otherwise you may be reading up with corrupted (e.g. half-written) values. (That was mentioned here by other before)

The other important thing in concurrent programming is visibility. If you wouldn't read-lock the VM might cache the old value and you won't see the new one. Sometimes even reordering can be an issue.

A really good book on this topic (and many others) is [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/). The free online article [Synchronization and the Java Memory Model](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html) by [Doug Lea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea) also covers it and might be a good start.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such class as `ReaderLock` in the standard Java SE class library.

If you are asking about "read locks" in general, the idea is to stop something else acquiring a write lock and writing to the file (or whatever) while we are reading it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are asking about synchronization. if so , u need to lock before using shared buffer by a reader. if not during reading a writter thread can write the shared buffer and you can read the wrong data. i am not sure whether you are asking this because your question is not clear.